# Proving that Two functionals are equal

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, riesz-representation-theorem

The following is an exercise from the third edition of *Functional Analysis* by B V Limaye  (p. 438):

> Let $f$ and $g$ be two continuous linear functionals on a Hilbert space $H$. $\|g\|=\|f\|$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ for some nonzero $x$ in $\ker(f)^\perp$. Prove that $f=g$.

We used the fact that $H$ can be written as a direct sum of $\ker(f)$ and its orthogonal complement. But it's not leading to anything. If someone can help us proceed it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Wlog $f(v)=\langle x,v\rangle$ for all $v\in H.$

Let $y\in H$ s.t. $g(v)=\langle y,v\rangle$ for all $v\in H.$

By hypothesis, $\|y\|=\|x\|$ and $\langle y,x\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle$ hence by the case of equality in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $y=x.$

Comment: How did you choose the element x on which f and g agree as the representer of f? ie, if f(x)=g(x) for some non zero x in $kerf^\perp$ how did you write f(v)=<x,v> for all v in H?

Comment: By [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem#Statement),$$\exists!x\in H\quad\forall v\in H\quad f(v)=\langle x,v\rangle.$$Then $\ker f=x^\perp$ hence $(\ker f)^\perp=\mathbb R x.$ And by hypothesis, $f$ and $g$ coincide on that subspace.